# Filter Array modifying the original array itself

Tags: javascript, filter

Is there any way to modify the original array with filter instead of returning a new one?
Just in case this is an XY problem, the reason to that is I want to modify the array inside a function:

```
function diff(myArray, removeArray){

   // this does not work of course
   myArray = myArray.filter(x => !removeArray.includes(x));
    
}
let myArray = [1,2,3];
diff(myArray, [2,4]);   
console.log(myArray);  // should be [1,3] here
```

I know I can remove the elements with some loop, but maybe there is a more elegant and efficient way to do that with filter directly?

Comment: As far as XY problems go, you could modify the function to return a new array instead of modifying the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always filter and clear array and add them back

```js
function cleanUp (arr) {
  const temp = arr.filter(x => x % 2);
  arr.length = 0;
  arr.push(...temp)
}

var myArr = [1,2,3,4];
cleanUp(myArr);
console.log(myArr);
```

doing it with splice

```js
function cleanUp (arr) {
  arr.push(...arr.splice(0, arr.length).filter(x => x % 2))
}

var myArr = [1,2,3,4];
cleanUp(myArr);
console.log(myArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really, I think iterating manually and removing elements that don't pass the test is the only way you can do something like that:

```js
function diff(myArray, removeArray) {
  for (let i = myArray.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (removeArray.includes(myArray[i])) {
      myArray.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
}
let myArray = [1, 2, 3];
diff(myArray, [2, 4]);
console.log(myArray); // should be [1,3] here
```

It's ugly. Returning a new array with `.filter` is probably preferable in almost all cases - it's not only easier to read, it's also more functional. (Code is generally easier to make sense of when unnecessary mutation is avoided)

Answer (score 0):

Besides @CertainPerformance answer, if you truly need this method to modify the original array, you can always override the `Array.prototype` method and implement one yourself:

```
Array.prototype.filter = function(callback, context){
  for (var i = this.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (!callback.call(context, this[i], i, this)) {
        this.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
};
```

> Note: `this` refers to the caller, in this case, the array in question.

Even though I would also advocate against it becomes harder to re-use, maintain and trace.